# Нагревается ноутбук при выполнении JS

Tags: javascript

Скрипт заставляет текст скроллиться по кругу отнимая margin-left и почему-то нагревая ноутбук. Во всяком случае в webkit браузерах. Можно ли это как-то исправить?

```js
window.requestAnimationFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
          function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();

var speed = 5000;
(function currencySlide(){
    var currencyPairWidth = $('.slideItem:first-child').outerWidth();
    $(".slideContainer").animate({marginLeft:-currencyPairWidth},speed, 'linear', function(){
                $(this).css({marginLeft:0}).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
        });
        requestAnimationFrame(currencySlide);
})();
```

```css
.slideItem {
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px;
  float: left;
}

.slide{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding-top: 70px;
}
.edge{
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
}
.edge:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
 
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
}
.edge:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    right:0;

    width:25%;
    height:100%;
}
ul{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:1000%;
    margin:0;
}
li{
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='slide'>
    <div class="edge"></div>
<ul class="slideContainer" id="money_start">
      <li class="slideItem">Текст1</li>
      <li class="slideItem">Текст2</li>
      <li class="slideItem">Текст3</li>
      <li class="slideItem">Текст4</li>
      <li class="slideItem">Текст5</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ноутбук греет функция request animation frame))

Comment: Сделайте css анимацию или svg

Comment: Волшебный ноут.....)))

Comment: В каждом кадре создаётся новая анимация...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да, теперь я понял как это работает. Наверное использую CSS, да. Просто, не хочется использовать эти огромные библиотеки для такой пустяковой фичи. Спасибо!

Comment: @Air Стив Джобс перевернулся)